# Fetching database that starts with number with R library RODBC

Tags: sql, r, fetch, special-characters, rodbc

How can I fetch database which starts with number with `RODBC` library in R? This code gives an error:

```
myconn <-odbcConnect("Database")
dat <- sqlFetch(myconn, "db.8798")
```

Error is (after displaying `dat` in R console):

> [1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '.8798'."
>
> [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM db.8798'"

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `sqlQuery` instead of `sqlFetch` (both of `RODBC` package)?

Comment: Yup, `sql.string <- 'select * from [db].[8798]'` and after
`dat <- data.frame(sqlQuery(myconn, sql.string))` does the job. Thanks!